# Как создать сквозную нумерацию в имени (запись в БД) при одновременной работе нескольких пользователей?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

С помощью С# записываю в MySql базу данных карточку, у которой есть регистрационный номер вида 'код района-код структурного подразделения-порядковый номер карточки'. Порядковый номер должен быть сквозным для всех специалистов, на данный момент под этот номер создана отдельная таблица num, с полем number, откуда программа его забирает, инкрементирует (добавляя к первым двум частям номера новой карточки) и записывает обратно. Я боюсь, что при такой схеме, при одновременном обращении к полю у разных людей могут получиться одинаковые идентификаторы, чего быть не должно. Подскажите, как можно решить этот момент?
P.S.: пример регистрационного номера
8003-3722-**21**
7900-8013-**22**
8003-3722-**23**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильное решение - хранить только префикс регистрационного номера (а ещё правильнее - каждый код в отдельном поле), плюс автоинкрементный первичный индекс. Полный регистрационный номер формировать в запросе, который получает данные из таблицы.

Возможное решение - опорная таблица для сквозной нумерации с единственным автоинкрементным полем и триггер BEFORE INSERT.

Comment: Эмм...
```begin; select id from tbl for update; update tbl set id=id+1;insert phone(id,....) values(id,...) ; commit;```

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Вот нафига такие заморочки? тупо `INSERT INTO base (id) VALUES (DEFAULT);` и далее используем `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. Автоинкремент сам разберётся...

Comment: Потому что автор изначально указал что использует внешнюю таблицу для хранения инкремента.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Вот и я совершенно о том же.

Comment: а, не так понял вопрос, например потому что система изначально так устроена(zabbix) для спокойного переезда между PGSQL <>MySQL <> MSSQL.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Гм... а каким тут боком заббикс-то? вроде о нём речи даже близко не было.

Comment: как пример для чего это делается и пример рабочей системы с подобной реализацией инкремента =)